# Grails - logging from Quartz job and Filter

Tags: file, grails, filter, quartz-scheduler, logging

I would like to stock my logs into files: 
Here is how I declare my appenders in Config.groovy:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
        file name: "scraperServiceDetailedLogger",
             file: "target/scraperServiceDetailed.log"    
        file name: "scraperServiceLogger",
             file: "target/scraperService.log"             
        file name: "filterLogger",
             file: "target/filter.log"      
    }

error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
error scraperServiceDetailedLogger: "grails.app.service.personalcreditcomparator.ScraperService"
info scraperServiceLogger: "grails.app.jobs.personalcreditcomparator.ScraperJob"
info filterLogger: "grails.app.conf.personalcreditcomparator.AdministratorInterfaceProtectorFilters"

}
```

The 3 files are created properly but only `scraperServiceDetailedLogger` stores the logs properly. The other two files remain empty.

The level of logging is respected while calling the `log`.

What am I missing ?

Thank you for any help provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For quartz jobs try the Logger prefix of 'grails.app.task'

```
info scraperServiceLogger: "grails.app.task.personalcreditcomparator.ScraperJob"
```

And for filters try the Logger prefix of 'grails.app.filters'

```
info filterLogger: "grails.app.filters.personalcreditcomparator.AdministratorInterfaceProtectorFilters"
```

Comment: For posterity, it now appears to be `grails.app.jobs...`